# Take entry in data in sparkR

Tags: apache, apache-spark-sql

I have a data 'p' and say I have a `vector` in `sparkR`
u=c(1,2,3,NA,4,5) like this.
I want to take the u entries in data 'p'.

In R I would simply do this
p[u,]
but how can I do it in `sparkR` ? 
When I type p[u,] it simply say
"Error: `object` of type 'S4' is not subsettable".

Comment: The vector u should be u=c(1,2,3,NA,5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you can only take al rows or the first row. In your case, actually only demanding the first 5 rows this would be,

```
head(p,5)
```

when u would equal c(1,5,9,20,35) this is not yet possible in SparkR, but I've read they are thinking about adding row.names (or row indexes)